# P4merge with GIT 2.18.0

Tags: git, merge, p4merge

I'm trying to make p4merge works with GIT thanks to [this little tutorial](https://gist.github.com/dgoguerra/8258007)

I don't understand what's wrong because I've tried severals ways to do it but I can't succeed in getting a visual interface with p4merge to see the differences between files when I create a merge conflict.

By the way, I'm just using the git bash to type the commands... I don't know if it can be a mistake ?

Here what it wrotes in my .gitconfig :

```
[diff]
  tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
  path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
[merge]
  tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
  path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
```

I'm working on Windows 7 and I just typed commands in the tutorial I gave in my post.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO :-) Do you expect us to magically guess 1) what *doesn't work* (commands typed, error message, which environment, etc.) and 2) what you've tried so far? [Help us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) helping you.

Comment: Of course not but I think I wrote all of the information I have got ?! 
Maybe I didn't understand how it works but when I type "git mergeTool" or "git diffTool", it just doing anything to invoke p4merge visual interface :/

Comment: Maybe give us a hint of what `git config --list` is outputting (but you did not give any of the 3 elements I suggested earlier (commands you typed, error message if any, and what's your OS/setting)

Comment: I gave informations in a new post ! :)

Comment: Editing your question would have been better, but whatever, that's more information anyway ^^

Comment: My comment on your answer (which has been deleted and moved into your question since) was "You should start by putting double quotes around the paths, because they contain whitespace".